# How can I get the coding region from gene sequences?

Tags: bioinformatics

So, I have a file with 600+ sequences of a gene, each one from a different population. This file was obtained after blasting the chromosome sequences against the gene sequence. However, I need the coding regions as well. Should I do the same and blast the chromosomes against the exons, or should I blast the gene sequences against the exons?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want the coding region, not the mRNA transcript right?  if so swbarnes2 answer to use blastx should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the exonic sequence is coding. The ends have 3' and 5' UTRs.

Can you find gtfs for your organism?  Those would be easier to work with.

Or, I'd do blastx against the protein, that should pull out just the sequence that codes for protein.